# Nested CSS styles are not applied in the Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm using Nextjs with `sass`(1.28.0). Unfortunately, the nested css styles are not applied in the webpage. Importing the below css file as `auth.module.scss` and there are no import errors also. This Application involves AMP pages as well.  Correct me if i'm missing anything.

```
 .loginForm{
    width:300px;

    .MuiFormControl-root{
      width:100%;
      margin-top:20px;
    }
}
```

Here is the `next.config.js`

```
const withPWA = require('next-pwa')
const runtimeCaching = require('next-pwa/cache')

module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: 'public',
    runtimeCaching,
  }
})
```

JSX

```
 <div className={auth.loginForm}>
   <TextField label="Email*" placeholder="Enter Email" autoComplete="current-email" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you show your JSX code as well?

Comment: if you are using material UI try using there docs to override components.Using `important!` might work but not a good approach

Comment: I have updated the `JSX`.Please have a look. @Vibhav this app involves AMP pages also. Therefore, adding `!important` to styles is not a good idea.Because, those styles will be removed by AMP scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Less for my project but the config should be similar. You will need to enable CSS module config for `next/sass`

```js
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [
      withSass,
      {
        cssModules: true,
        cssLoaderOptions: {
          sourceMap: true,
          localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
          localsConvention: 'camelCase',
          camelCase: 'dashes',
        },
      },
    ],
    [withCSS],
  ],
  ....... // some other global config
);
```

Without `next-compose-plugins`, you can probably do something like the following

```js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')

module.exports = withSass({
  cssModules: true,
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
  }
})
```